# Identifying required packages from code

Tags: r

I want to follow the tutorial found on [this site](https://www.r-bloggers.com/backtesting-a-trading-strategy/), but despite being thorough in all other aspects, the author has not included information on what packages need to be used for the code to function.

As far as I understand one of them will be the `PerformanceAnalytics` package, yet my inexperienced eye is not sure about what else I will need to include.

The `fapply` function used in the code is one example that I cannot find.

```
fapply()
```

> Error: could not find function "fapply"

Answer (score 3):

```
library(sos)
findFn("fapply", sortby = "Function")
```

Answer (score 2):

The findFN(...) function is great. It should open an internet browser window with the search results by itself at least it does for me.

Answer (score 1):

The tutorial on **Backtesting a Trading Strategy** uses time series data as seen its part 1 and part 2. **fapply** is also used in part 2

As the data being collected and processed is **time-series** data, [fapply()](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/far/versions/0.6-5/topics/fapply) function belongs to [far](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/far/versions/0.6-5) package which is used for Modelization for Functional AutoRegressive Processes.
I hope this helps.